# How to receive JSONArray

Tags: android, json, url

Following guide I see this:

```
  JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("nome_stanza"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("icona"));

                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });
  AppController2.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq); //i need this movieReq
```

But I don't have a URL where the Jsoncode is collocated, I receive jsoncode from another method that gives me a string like this:

```
{"risposta_server": [{"nome_stanza":"via oslavia"},{"icona":"http:\/\/****.**.**.**\/fil***\/****\/images\/icon\/icon2.png"},{"Admin":"s"}]}
```

Then, how can I change the first code to use this result?

Comment: that mean you dont have problem in receiving jsonarray  , as you said I recive jsoncode from another method

Comment: All the object in your array doesn't contains the same structure... Some has "nome_stanza" some contains "icona"

Comment: Also, is this an Object you are retriving or an Array? because your Array starts with [ {  and ends with } ] }

Comment: Your post is too confusing... I don't get what you are trying to say sorry

Comment: .. `new JsonArrayRequest(URL, ...`  see URL? I haven't URL.. But i recive json response `{"risposta_server": [{"nome_stanza":"via oslavia"},{"icona":"http:\/\/****.**.**.**\/fil***\/****\/images\/icon\/icon2.png"},{"Admin":"s"}]}` by other class.. now how can i change `JsonArrayRequest` method without URL?

Comment: I only need movieReq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got mixed up in response, but I understand it's supposed to come `Json Object`.The next step:

```
JSONOArray array = response.getJSONArrary("risposta_server");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   try {
       JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
       Movie movie = new Movie();
        if(i == 0){
          movie.setTitle(obj.getString("nome_stanza"));
        }else if(i == 1){
           movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("icona"));
        }
        movieList.add(movie);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 ...
```

See the job if I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need json encode like `json_encode($str)` on php script. Where `$str` is an array list.
So, your server script will be like this

```
$arr = array('hello', 'world', 'where', 'i', 'life');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then you will get json data from server